# Python - Strange Behavior in re.sub

Tags: python, regex

Here's the code I'm running:

```
import re

FIND_TERM = r'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\90\\DTS\\Binn\\DTExec\.exe'
rfind_term = re.compile(FIND_TERM,re.I)

REPLACE_TERM = 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100\\DTS\\Binn\\DTExec.exe'

test = r'something C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe something'

print rfind_term.sub(REPLACE_TERM,test)
```

And the result I get is:

```
something C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server@\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe something
```

Why is there an @ sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RE engine is treating the `\100` in `REPLACE_TERM` as an octal escape code. You need to escape the backslash so that it's treated as desired.

Comment: But I'm already escaping the backslash.  Why would I need to escape it twice?

Comment: You're escaping the backslash for Python. You still need to escape it for the `re` engine, so that it isn't considered a backreference or octal escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing raw ( r'' ) and normal strings.

```
>>> FIND_TERM = r'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\90\\DTS\\Binn\\DTExec\.exe'
>>> REPLACE_TERM = r'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100\\DTS\\Binn\\DTExec.exe' 
>>> rfind_term = re.compile(FIND_TERM,re.I)
>>> test = r'something C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe something'
>>> print rfind_term.sub(REPLACE_TERM,test) 
something C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe something
```

Comment: why do you need r' and double backslahes in the replace term?  Is it because it thinks replace term is a regular expression?